# Sonnar runner in Jenkins error in java project

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am trying to analyse my solution .java using sonar 5.5.1. from Jenkins. But when execute sonar runner in Jenkins, it failing with following messages:

```
11:41:05.158 INFO  - Sensor CoberturaSensor (done) | time=0ms<br>
11:41:05.158 INFO  - Sensor SCM Sensor<br>
11:41:05.158 INFO  - SCM provider for this project is: git<br>
11:41:05.162 INFO  - 8 files to be analyzed<br>
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------<br>
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE<br>
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------<br>
Total time: 6.398s<br>
Final Memory: 32M/114M<br>
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------<br>
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution<br>
org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar<br>
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)<br>
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:229)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.LinkageError: org.eclipse.jgit.diff.RawTextComparator
at org.sonar.plugins.scm.git.JGitBlameCommand.waitForTaskToComplete(JGitBlameCommand.java:77)
at org.sonar.plugins.scm.git.JGitBlameCommand.blame(JGitBlameCommand.java:64)
at org.sonar.batch.scm.ScmSensor.execute(ScmSensor.java:84)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.SensorWrapper.analyse(SensorWrapper.java:59)
at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:59)
at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:51)
at org.sonar.batch.phases.DatabaseModePhaseExecutor.execute(DatabaseModePhaseExecutor.java:120)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:264)
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:235)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:230)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:220)
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:57)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:45)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:135)
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:158)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:95)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
... 9 more
```

The plugins installed are:

> sonar-android-plugin-1.1.jar 
>   sonar-build-stability-plugin-1.3.jar
>   sonar-clover-plugin-3.0.jar
>  sonar-cobertura-plugin-1.6.3.jar
>   sonar-cpp-plugin-3.6.jar
>  sonar-css-plugin-1.2.jar
>   sonar-findbugs-plugin-3.2.jar
>   sonar-generic-coverage-plugin-1.1.jar
>   sonar-issue-assign-plugin-1.6.jar
>  sonar-java-plugin-3.3.jar
>   sonar-javascript-plugin-2.6.jar
>   sonar-motion-chart-plugin-1.7.jar
>  sonar-php-plugin-2.6.jar
>   sonar-pmd-plugin-2.4.1.jar
>  sonar-python-plugin-1.5.jar
>   sonar-scm-git-plugin-1.1.jar
>  sonar-scm-stats-plugin-0.3.1.jar
>   sonar-scm-svn-plugin-1.1.jar
>   sonar-tab-metrics-plugin-1.4.1.jar
>   sonar-timeline-plugin-1.5.jar
>  sonar-web-plugin-2.3.jar
>   sonar-widget-lab-plugin-1.7.jar
>  sonar-xml-plugin-1.2.jar

I tried some settings but does not work me, I have not any idea hot to fix it.
Can you help me please.

Comment: You can try to disable the SCM provider (git), and see if you have any other issues

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen this error. The Git plugin seems to be corrupted. Please try to remove/reinstall it on your server. The corruption may also occurs in local plugin cache (in ~/.sonar/cache) so maybe you can try removing this directory and restarting the analysis.